# Escaped Criminal radiant quest - criminal does not spawn

Tags: pc, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So, I have a quest from Skjor, if I remember correctly, which tells me that a wanted criminal has escaped and was last seen going around The Pale, or something to that effect. The problem is that the objective arrow doesn't lead anywhere - while I'm in Whiterun, the arrow points to the gate leading out of the city; if I'm outside Whiterun, the arrow points to the gate leading back in to the city.

I read over on the [UESPWiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Escaped_Criminal) that it's possible to proceed through the quest using console commands, but they don't seem to work for me.

Suggestions, please?

Comment: I have the same problem. It is not a matter of the quest marker moving. The problem is it is stuck on the Whiterun City Gate. I dont know the consol command to complete it. Hope someone figures this out soon. Im on PC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to remove quest from Journal w/ "SetObjectiveCompleted CR07 10 0" and "SetOBjectiveCompleteed CR07 0 0"... but Vilkas still thinks it's uncompleted.

This one seems hopeless.

Answer (score 3):

I found the [Clairvoyance](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Clairvoyance) spell to be very handy in this quest.

Comment: I am in exact same situation as the person who asked the question - the quest is given to find a "criminal wandering Whiterun", and quest marker is on the gate leading outside when inside the sity, and on the gate leading inside when outside it. Clairvoyance is no help at all, since it gives the same exact indication when used - always at the city gates.

Comment: more of the same.  criminal in markarth does not spawn for me.  clairvoyance, quest markers, et al do not work.  i would be satisfied with removing it from my quest list...setstage cr07 also does not work

Answer (score 0):

It does spawn but it's constantly moving.  I spent like 2 days (real time) running around chasing quest markers and eventually just waiting on a road for her to wander by where I had seen her before.